# Batch Script "for /f ..."

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
for /F "skip=n tokens=3 delims= " %%i in (myfile.txt) do echo %%i
```

Is it possible for `skip=n ...` to be a variable like `skip=%test% ...` where `%test%` has an integer value?

So I'm trying to add a column of data and the location of this table in the file is given by a string.

For Eg:

```
$startTable 

0 1 4

1 2 4

2 1 4 

$endTable
```

So the location of this table is given by the line number associated with $startTable. I have the value of this stored in a variable(!test!) so I need the skip=!test! and then I start adding the third column until I hit $endTable.

When I try;

```
for /f "skip=!test! tokens=3 delims= " %%j in (!INPUTFILE!) do (
echo %%j
if %%j == "$endTable" goto :break
set /a test2+=%%j
)
:break
```

I get the following error;

```
!test! tokens=3 delims= " was unexpected at this time.
```

-GK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for doesn't like to take the delayed expansion syntax inside the parameters.  That should be fine, since you don't need it.  Use the standard % wrapped variable, instead - that's what Michael and Jebego's examples are using.

If you really want to use the delayed expansion version, you'll need a temp variable to do it:

```
set for_parameters="skip=!test! tokens=3 delims= "
for /f %for_parameters% %%j in (!INPUTFILE!) do ( echo %%j
```

EDIT: Here's what I'm running, trying to stay close to your original parameter names.  I changed the input to show that %j is updating and which rows are parsed.

stackoverflow_input.txt

```
$startTable

0 1 3

1 2 4

2 1 5

$endTable
```

stackoverflow1.bat

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set INPUTFILE=stackoverflow_input.txt
set test=3
set test2=0
set for_parameters="skip=!test! tokens=3 delims= "
for /f %for_parameters% %%j in (!INPUTFILE!) do (
echo %%j
if %%j == "#endTable" goto :break
set /a test2+=%%j
)
:break
echo Sum: %test2%
endlocal
```

stackoverflow2.bat

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set INPUTFILE=stackoverflow_input.txt
set test=3
set test2=0
for /f "skip=%test% tokens=3 delims= " %%j in (!INPUTFILE!) do (
echo %%j
if %%j == "#endTable" goto :break
set /a test2+=%%j
)
:break
echo Sum: %test2%
endlocal
```

Results (verified same on Win 7, Server 2008R2, Server 2003, and Win XP SP3):

```
D:\temp>stackoverflow1.bat
4
5
Sum: 9

D:\temp>stackoverflow2.bat
4
5
Sum: 9
```

If command extensions are disabled, you'll instead get: `/f was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: I tried this and for some reason the for statement fails to process the %for_parameters% variable. The for treats this as if the parameters were not present.

Comment: Try putting an echo after the set to be sure it is working as you expect.  Also, make sure there is no space between for_parameters and the equal sign after it.  (Or just use %test% in your original instead of !test!. :) )

Comment: When I echo after the set it gives me the right value for "for_parameters" which is `"skip=100 tokens=3 delims= "` where, `!test!=100` but it fails to work. Also I tried using `%test%` instead of for_parameters and it does not work and complains saying `"tokens=3 delims= " was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: I tried your code and found that cmd doesn't like what we were doing inside a `if... else` loop. When I put in what you suggested outside the `if... else` loop it worked like a charm. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
set num=2
for /F "skip=%num% tokens=3 delims= " %%i in (myfile.txt) do echo %%i
```

This will skip the first two lines. You could have just tried to add the variable!

Comment: Please check revised explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This will echo the 4th and subsequent lines of test.txt

```
set sk=3  
for /f "skip=%sk% delims=" %%L in (test.txt) do (  
    echo %%L  
    )
```

Comment: Please check revised explanation.